# Story about teleportation gateways that make the user younger

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a science fiction story I read years ago, about teleportation gateways that the user finds are making him younger when he travels through them.

Comment: This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: The more information you can provide about the story (and when/where you read it), the more likely it is that someone can identify it for you. We recommend that you look at our Guide: [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see what info you can add to this question.

Comment: Having said that, I immediately thought of Niven, _A World Out of Time_.

Comment: Larry Niven's "A World Out of Time" occured to me too.  It uses this idea.  The protagonist was a man from our near future who becomes a starship pilot.  Time dilation places him in a far future solar system with a very changed Earth, now orbiting Jupiter.  Do the words "Dicta" or "Boys" mean anything to you?

Comment: "Fax machines" that heal injuries and restore yiuth, making people effectively immortal, are a prominent feature of Wil McCarthy's [Queendom of Sol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Queendom_of_Sol) novels, starting with _[The Collapsium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Collapsium)_. There's also a lot of dangerous mucking-about with gravity.

Comment: I, too, thought of Niven's *World Out of Time*. The hero encounters a teleportation booth that apparently doesn't do anything except make the dust at the bottom swirl. He later realizes that the booth teleported all the dead cells and accumulated poison in living cells out of his body, hence reversing ageing.

Comment: I'm a very terse person. The only other thing I remember is that it was part of an anthology.

Answer (score 3):

This is not much to go by, but in *Exile's Gate*, the fourth of the novels about the heroine Morgaine by C. J. Cherryh, the viewpoint character (Margaine's ronin servant, Nhi Vanye) is reverted to a fixed age every time he passes through a teleportation gate.  Morgaine had programmed the gates to do this, to heal his injuries.

Since the plot of the whole series involves Morgaine traveling from planet to planet through the gates and closing them behind her, this is a potentially important plot point.  It means that Vanye will not be able to outgrow his approximately twenty-year-old appearance as long as he continues to travel through the gates.  However, since the novels ended after *Exile's Gate*, the issue was not pursued too extensively.

[image: Exile's Gate]

Comment: When finding out about it, Vanye was unhappy about not getting his final growth.

Answer (score 1):

This might possibly be the Damon Knight story "Ticket to Anywhere" (1952.)  It has a network of teleportation booths that don't make you younger, but do temporarily stop the aging process while you're using them.  You can read [a copy at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1952-04/page/n135), and it's been [anthologized a number of times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56249).